# charAt(0) Not returning first number but second

Tags: java

Piglatin translator. at the end I am trying to get the location of the first vowel. Index is set to be the location of every vowel, but with pig latin you only need the location of the first vowel. When I run the program I don't always get the location of the first vowel. it seems to give me the second number and not the first.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Assignment_4_Piglatin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userWord = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("K. Caleb Swallow");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!");

        boolean run = true;
        while (run) {

            System.out.println("Please enter a word(or press Q to quit):");

            String firstLetter = "something";
            String firstVowel = "test";

            String word = userWord.next();
            String vowels = "aeiou";
            if (word.equals("Q")) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

            firstLetter = Character.toString(word.charAt(0));

            if (firstLetter.equals("a") || firstLetter.equals("e") || firstLetter.equals("i") || firstLetter.equals("o") || firstLetter.equals("u")) {
                System.out.println(word + "way");
            } else {
                for (int index = 0; index < word.length(); index++) {
                    if (vowels.contains(String.valueOf(word.charAt(index)))) {
                        System.out.print(index);
                        String firstNumber = Integer.toString(index);
                        firstVowel = Character.toString(firstNumber.charAt(0));

                    }
                }

            }
            System.out.println(firstVowel);
```

Comment: Try to format your code before posting it here (e.g. http://www.freecodeformat.com/java-format.php)

Comment: Are uppercase letters considered as valid input to your program?

Comment: Add a break statement after the first vowel has been found so that the for loop stops iterating.

Comment: By the way shouldn't you consider "y" a vowel?

Comment: how do i add a break statement?

Comment: @Mr.Swallow3 there are a couple of solutions below which show how to break out of the loop.

Comment: Also @asettouf also makes a good point, I didn't notice the lack of "y" in the vowels.

Answer (score 0):

The example seems to have some redundant code in `if..else` condition. If you want to print the first vowels then you can do it with a simple `for` loop, e.g.:

```
String word = userWord.next().toLowerCase();
String vowels = "aeiou";
for(int i=0 ; i<word.length() ; i++){
    if(vowels.contains(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)))){
        System.out.println(word.charAt(i));
        break;
    }
}
```

Please note that you need to do `toLowerCase` on the actual word in order for `contains` to work.

Answer (score 0):

`public static void main(String[] args) {`

```
            Scanner userWord = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("K. Caleb Swallow");
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!");

            boolean run = true;
            while (run) {

                System.out.println("Please enter a word(or press Q to quit):");

                String firstLetter = "something";
                String firstVowel = "test";

                String word = userWord.next();
                ArrayList<Character> vowels = new ArrayList<>();
                vowels.add('a');
                vowels.add('e');
                vowels.add('i');
                vowels.add('o');
                vowels.add('u');
                if (word.equals("Q")) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                firstLetter = Character.toString(word.charAt(0));

                if (firstLetter.equals("a") || firstLetter.equals("e") || firstLetter.equals("i") || firstLetter.equals("o") || firstLetter.equals("u")) {
                    System.out.println(word + "way");
                } else {
                    for (int index = 0; index < word.length(); index++) {
                        char indchar = word.charAt(index);
                        if (vowels.contains(word.charAt(index))) {
                            System.out.println(index);
                            firstVowel = Character.toString(word.charAt(index));
                            System.out.println(firstVowel);
                            index = word.length();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is how I would do it. I changed the vowels String to an ArrayList so you can easily check if the char in the String word with the index is a vowel and the code works absolutely fine. It returns you the index where the first vowel is and what vowel it is.

Comment: In this case, I would use break rather than return here, since it appears the author wants the program to loop until "Q" is entered.

Comment: I think this will still return the last vowel instead of the first one. Inserting "break;" at the end of the if-statement will solve this.

Comment: I works fine. It always returns the first vowel of the word you typed in. And break is equal to index = word.length(); because both will stop the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems I can see off the bat, but the one that is likely causing this error is in these lines:

```
String firstNumber = Integer.toString(index);
firstVowel = Character.toString(firstNumber.charAt(0));
```

Think about what this is doing. First, you are making a `String` out of the index value, then you are saying that the first vowel is at the 0th index of that string.

Think of this example: hello

The program will run and assign "4" to `firstNumber` and `firstVowel` which isn't what you want.

However, if you only have one vowel, your program will "work".

What happens if you have over ten vowels? I know this isn't a realistic example, but say it happens. Your program will assign the index of the last vowel to `firstNumber` (say it's 15), then it will assign the first character of that to `firstVowel` (1). This doesn't make much sense at all, does it, especially if you don't have a vowel in index 1.

The main problem you are encountering for words less than 10 letters in length is that you are not just outputting the second number, you are outputting the last one. One way I like to deal with this is to go through the code and put in print statements where I'm not sure what a certain value is. For example, I'd put another print statement in your loop which tells you what letter you're looking at, like so:

```
System.out.println("LETTER: "+ String.valueOf(word.charAt(index)));
```

This will help you avoid confusion. The proper way to do this problem would be to use a `break` statement, such as in Darshan's answer. Alternatively, you could use the properties of the for loop:

```
firstVowel = "";
for (int index = 0; index < word.length() && firstVowel == ""; index++) {
CODE
}
```

Note that the second part of the `for` loop is a conditional statement. You already know that this can be used to cycle through the word's characters, but you can insert any logical statement there that you want. For this example, I set the default value of `firstVowel` to `""` (setting it to `null` is a faux-pas, but that's another story). Then, each time the loop runs, it checks to see if the value of `firstVowel` has been changed, which will of course happen on the first time a vowel is run through the loop.

So in short, you need to modify the two lines at the beginning of my post and you need to find a way to break your loop when you find the first vowel. One solution has been given here, and another in Darshan Mehta's post.